# Utilizar Methodo dentro de outro Methodo com classe extends

Tags: php, classes, herança

Olá, estou aprendendo PHP e estou com um problema de herança entre classes.

tenho um classe para conexão e uma outra para crud porem não consigo usar a conexão na na classe de crud.

alguém pode me ajudar com o erro?

Grato!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ainda bem, né? Porque herança deve ser usada para coisas que tem relação direta, ou seja, a classe filha, tem que ser exatamente a mesma coisa que a classe mãe com algo a mais ou diferente, herança não existe pra juntar duas coisas que nada tem a ver com uma com a outra.

Comment: Boa noite, Reinaldo. Você esqueceu o `$this->` ao chamar o método da classe mãe.

Comment: Fico sem entender "obsessão" em diversas perguntas e em programadores,  em usar OOP para coisas relativamente simples pq alguem disse que vai ficar "melhor". Penso eu que qualquer coisa "mais avançada" deveria ser usada conforme a necessidade real e não porque todo mundo usa ou porque acha que vai ficar mais bonito/fácil. Até entendo o "abstrair" que as pessoas buscam tanto, mas o problema é que simplesmente o uso de OOP acaba virando uma salada ao invés de resolver os problemas, isso pq me parece que muita gente tem a visão errada do oop. É só uma duvida minha, não leve a mal. (cc @Maniero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema é bem simples de resolver. Existe uma pseudo-variável no PHP chamada `$this` que representa o contexto do objeto, com ela você pode acessar o que o seu objeto representa, seja: métodos, variáveis e inclusive métodos e variáveis herdadas.

No seu caso, o problema pode ser resolvido alterando `getConnection()` que está dentro do método `getPlanejadores()` para `$this->getConnection()`. Se observar o que aconteceu com essa mudança, estamos falando que queremos acessar dentro do nosso objeto (utilizando `$this`) o método `getConnection()`. Ficou claro?

Dessa maneira seu problema está resolvido, porém gostaria de alertá-lo de uma coisa. Como você comentou, está aprendendo PHP ainda e tudo bem, porém nesse exemplo seu você utilizou herança de maneira errada. Você utiliza herança quando quer criar um sub-tipo de algo, no caso, você utilizaria herança quando quiser criar um sub-tipo de `Connection` mas `Planejador` não é um sub-tipo de `Connection`, ele apenas utiliza. Aconselho também nessa jornada sua de estudos, se aprofundar um pouco em orientação a objetos.